# How to display RDL report in WPF for user to edit and save

Tags: wpf, rdl

we have a large number of existing reports (.rdl files), the business need is to enable business users to change the text on those report directly, they don't have report designer of any sort.

So requirement is to create a WPF app, that will allow user to browse to one of those reports, display them in readable format (not as xml but formatted similar to what the real report looks like, as if they are opened in the designer), and then allow user to update the text (essentially the contents inside those  tags), and save the report. so when it's ran it'll reflect those title, heading, text etc. changes.

Did some research there are something like ReportViewer, Syncfusion reportviewer that can take care of displaying part in WPF, but none of them seems to allow user to edit and save.

Are there any suggestions on what are the options to achieve this? I am thinking creating some mapping/translating between those xml tags and html so the content can be displayed in a readable format, and put those user editable fields in array of values to keep track of changes and replace back to the original .rdl file. but that all seem too complicated and also performance can be a concern...there should be a better way!

your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having these values stored inside the report, I would store them in the database. Don't have any static values in the report. Everything shown in the report is loaded as paramters that can be configured.

This way you can create a UI that allows you to change the values of these configurations and a button to load the report viewer with a fresh version of the report using these values. This wouldn't be a full on report editor but if you created some base templates that meet the business needs, they'd be able to make some general modifications to the report such as Titles, alignment, logos, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! yes that was what i thought first too, but i was told there are so many reports it's not pratical to revise all of them. and we are not the sole owner of those reports either. we started putting together some dynamically generated stackpanels and textboxes to display them in wpf and allow editting, it's actually turned out pretty nice, better than i thought. But I still want to get suggestions on better approaches. thanks again!